# How do I add sdk's to a kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating a kivy app for android and I want to integrate an sdk but I can't seem to figure out how to build an apk with it integrated. So far none of the guides I've found have been helpful.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to put a Software Development Kit inside your app??

Comment: I'm trying to add an sdk such as the admob sdk

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of working with *AdBuddiz* a similar solution can be applied with *admob* using **jnius**

```
#ads.py
from jnius import autoclass
import logging
import random
log = logging.getLogger('kivy.funky.stuff')
PythonActivity=autoclass("org.renpy.android.PythonActivity")
AdBuddiz=autoclass("com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk.AdBuddiz")

AD_CHANCE = 0.06

def init():
    AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("some-token")
    #delete this before going to play at the store...
    AdBuddiz.setTestModeActive()
    AdBuddiz.cacheAds(PythonActivity.mActivity)

def show():
    if (random.random() < AD_CHANCE):
        log.info("Showing Ad!!!")
        try:
            AdBuddiz.showAd(PythonActivity.mActivity)
        except Exception:
            log.exception("Pizza is not healthy...")
    else:

        log.warn("Skipping the AD this time ;)")
```

to make this work you'll need to add **pyjnius** to your buildozer.spec as well as the java SDK (i.e. android.add_jars = %(source.dir)s/libs/*.jar).